# Error when attempting to install network printer/driver using PrintUI command

Tags: drivers, printer, command, printing

I receive the following error when attempting to install a TCP/IP printer using PrintUI:

> "Operation could not be completed (error 0x00000705). Windows cannot
>   locate a suitable printer driver. Contact your administrator for help
>   locating and installing a suitable driver."

This is the command line I'm using to load a **signed** PCL6 driver for a Canon iR3235 printer:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /b "printer" /f "c:\canonimagerunner\P62KUSAL.inf" /r "IP_192.168.152.41" /m "Front Desk"
```

Manually installing this same printer/driver through the "add printer" wizard is successful.

I resorted to using PrintUI instead of Group Policy printer management because that method was also failing to load this printer from a shared server instance, perhaps due to the same core driver dependency issue. We are testing this on a 32-bit Windows 7 Enterprise workstation, running the command line under a domain admin account.

We have already hit a dead-end in the Microsoft forums as seen here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprogeneral/thread/ea0f6b15-4bad-40a8-8f35-5c7993703ceb

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

/m must match the name of the printer in the INF file.  INF files can contain multiple printers so the error is most likely because it doesn't know which printer from the INF to install.  You will need to look in the INF to determine the printer you want.  I would also change your /b to Front Desk.

Example:  rundll32.exe printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /if /f "C:\Windows\System32\DriverStor
e\FileRepository\prnhp002.inf_amd64_neutral_04d05d1f6a90ea24\prnhp002.inf" /b "S
ybase DataWindow PS" /m "HP LaserJet 2300 Series PS" /r "FILE:" /u /Y